# How can I get ArcGIS Server to give a GML GetFeatureInfo response?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, getfeatureinfo

Although I have read the following document (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005300000228000000) I am still totally unsure about how to enable a gml GetFeatureInfo response from ArcGIS Server 10.0 . Is this something on the client-side that needs to be implemented or something in my GetCapabilities Document?

Answer (score 1):

If your GetCapabilities response has the following MIME type set then your client will be able to request GML.

```
application/vnd.ogc.gml
```

The GetFeatureInfo request requires the following name=value parameter pair

```
info_format=application/vnd.ogc.gml&
```

**EDIT** (Following comments)

As ArGIS 10 no longer supports gml out-of-the-box, one solution is to create your own XSLT template in *\Styles\WMS* called *featureinfo_application_vnd.ogc.gml.xsl*

An alternative method would be to use [EXOWS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/exows/)

Comment: I can only see the following mime types in my getCapabilities document. <GetFeatureInfo>
    <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_raw_xml</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_featureinfo_xml</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
    <Format>text/xml</Format>
    <Format>text/html</Format>
    <Format>text/plain</Format>

Comment: My mistake, re-reading my reference (http://onegeology.org/wmsCookbook/5_2_3.html), ArcGIS 9.3.1 reported that it supported application/vnd.ogc.gml but in fact only supplied XML as a response.  "Our latest understanding from ESRI is that application/vnd.ogc.gml will NOT be supported in 10, though you will be able to create non-geometry GML by creating a template."   I see too looking at an ArcGIS 10.2 service that your experience is no oversight, application/vnd.ogc.gml is no longer supported.